# Drawing text on GTK's DrawingArea in Haskell

Tags: haskell, gtk, pango, gtk2hs

I have a `DrawingArea` onto which I can draw using primitives such as `drawRectangle` and `drawLine`. How do I draw text onto that area? I'm most interested in something that quickly outputs a single line of text.

`Graphics.UI.Gtk.Gdk.Drawable.layoutLine` seems to be what I want, but it wants a `Graphics.Rendering.Pango.Layout.LayoutLine` as input. How do I construct that `LayoutLine`?

Are there better alternatives than doing it this way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the way to do this with Pango.

```
layout <- widgetCreateLayout drawAreaWidget stringToDraw
```

Then you can use this newly-created layout with functions such as `drawLayout` and `drawLayoutWithColors`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you would consider using Cairo. If so, I think the function `showText` may be what you are looking for. Use the cairo function `moveTo` to move to a specific location before writing the text. This is one of the simplest working examples I can produce:

```
import Graphics.UI.Gtk
import Graphics.Rendering.Cairo

main :: IO ()
main = do
    initGUI
    window      <- windowNew
    drawingArea <- drawingAreaNew
    containerAdd window drawingArea

    drawingArea `onExpose` (\_ -> renderScene drawingArea)
    window `onDestroy` mainQuit

    windowSetDefaultSize window 640 480
    widgetShowAll window
    mainGUI

renderScene :: DrawingArea -> IO Bool
renderScene da = do
    dw <- widgetGetDrawWindow da
    renderWithDrawable dw $ do setSourceRGBA 0.5 0.5 0.5 1.0
                               moveTo 100.0 100.0
                               showText "HelloWorld"
    return True
```

I found the following to be an excellent guide, even though it was not for Haskell:
http://zetcode.com/tutorials/cairographicstutorial/cairotext/